# как организовать данную структуру БД

Tags: mysql, sql

Суть: пользователь выбирает период пользования, оплачивает и получает доступ. Период заканчивается доступ закрывается. Моя структура работы следующая:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `email` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

//Таблица периодов пользования, а также сумма за период пользования
    CREATE TABLE `settings` (
        `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `price` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
        `start` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL, //начальная дата 
        `end` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL, //конечная дата
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    )
//История оплаты за пользования
    CREATE TABLE `payments` (
        `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `suma` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
        `created_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        `user_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        `payment_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
        INDEX `FK_payments_users` (`user_id`),
        CONSTRAINT `FK_payments_users` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
    )
```

Как проверять  давать ли пользователю доступ или нет ?

Comment: Таблица settings очень странно выглядит. Что в ней ? и как она связана с остальными таблицами

Comment: Забыл добавить в payments id_setting

Comment: Тогда это еще более странная таблица. Или вы предполагаете, что два платежа могут указывать на один период ? И как тогда быть если заплатили скажем за 2 месяца ?

Comment: Не, один платеж отвечает за один период. Вот у меня  в том то и вопрос, как быть если заплатили за 2 месяца.

Comment: А тогда зачем отдельная таблица, почему бы даты начала и окончания оплаченного периода не положить в payments ?

Comment: В таблицу settings, админ забивает периоды и цену за пользования. Юзер заходит на страницу и выберает из списка нужный период, нажимает оплатить и получает доступ. А в таблице payments хранится история оплат.

Comment: Вот собственно и вопрос как быть, если сегодня он заплатил за один период, а завтра за второй период учитывая то, что этот период еще не закончился.

Comment: Стоп. Еще проблема. в settings нет id пользователя. админ создает в ней запись для каждого пользователя отдельно ? Если да - то там точно нужен user_id. Если нет ... то я опять ничего не понимаю. Если админ делает запись с 4 декабря до 4 января, а какой то пользователь пришел 10 декабря и хочет с этого дня за месяц заплатить

Comment: Да в settings для всех одинаково. По поводу  4 декабря до 4 января, а какой то пользователь пришел 10 , нужно уточнить будет мне.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32482/discussion-between-mike-and-depredator).

Answer (score 1):

Сделать 4 таблицы: 1)пользователи, 2)периоды, 3)платежи-клиенты-суммы, и 4)связь платежей с периодами.
И давать доступ, если в 4 таблице оплачена полная стоимость периода. Ну и период еще не вышел по дате.